# How to configure Grep Console for Intellij

Tags: regex, plugins, intellij-idea, settings

I installed plugin for colorful console output for Intellij - [Grep Console](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125?pr=phpStorm)

I configured it for good looking.

But I have some trouble for configuring output for ***Exceptions***.

It filled only some part of thrown exception:

[image]

Here how looks configuration for this plugin:

[image]

It uses next regular expression for ***Exception***:

> [Exception].*

***How to include rest part of thrown exception with regular expression?***

Answer (score 1):

Tick `Enable multiline output` to color, also following lines which do not contain `Exception`.

Comment: It doesn't work. I want to include for new color pattern rest of exception. As phrases `caused by ..` and `at ...`

Comment: This works: `[Exception| at|Caused by].*` - notice the tab character, if you just copypaste the begining of lines you want to match, then it will work fine.

Comment: For me it fills all text at console to `exception` color. I want to achieve fill not exception output to nice color looking.

Comment: This solution aggressively coloured more output than I expected. I fixed it by setting up a filter that caught INFO lines.